# ASP .NET Core no HSTS header in response headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.2

In my `appsettings.json` i added this line of code:

```
"Hsts": {
    "HstsEnable": true
 }
```

In `launchSettings.json` i added `https://localhost:5000`:

```
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001;https://localhost:5000"
```

Then, in `Program.cs` i used this urls:

```
 return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(x => x.AddServerHeader = false)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001", "https://localhost:5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
```

In startup class, in `Configure` method im getting `Hsts` value from `appSettings.json`:

```
if (Configuration.GetSection("Hsts").GetValue<bool>("HstsEnable"))
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

After all this steps i cant get `Strict-Transport-Security`. All i get from response headers are:

```
 cache-control: no-store,no-cache 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 pragma: no-cache
```

The `Hsts` cutted headers from response. Without all this lines of code (to set up `hsts` in my app) on top i get this response headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true 
access-control-allow-origin: * 
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Disposition 
cache-control: no-store,no-cache 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
date: Fri, 11 Oct 2019 09:21:30 GMT 
pragma: no-cache 
transfer-encoding: chunked 
vary: Origin 
x-frame-options: DENY 
x-stackifyid: id
```

So something is wrong on this `Hsts`.

How to add `HSTS` header in response headers, that i mentioned above? Do i need to hardcode header to my `Configure` method?

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
```

Comment: What's the URL you use for the requests you make to test this?

Comment: @KirkLarkin `http://localhost:5001/`

Comment: The HSTS middleware doesn't add the HSTS headers for requests on loopback addresses. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts) (the end of that section).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the official documentation on [HTTP Strict Transport Security Protocol (HSTS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts)

`UseHsts` excludes the following loopback hosts:

- localhost : The IPv4 loopback address.
- 127.0.0.1 : The IPv4 loopback address.
- [::1] : The IPv6 loopback address.

You could try to publish the web app and check the header **Strict-Transport-Security**.